# uiscrollview laggging while scrolling horizontally on iPad

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uiscrollview

I am using swift3 my app contains UIscrollview for horizontal scrolling.  It contains images with paging. Below is the code sample of it.

```
for index in 0..<storyImages.count { 
       frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(index)
       frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size
       self.scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
        print(self.scrollView.bounds.width * CGFloat(index))
      let rect = CGRect(x: CGFloat(self.scrollView.bounds.width * CGFloat(index)), y: 0, width: scrollViewWidth , height: scrollViewHeight)
      let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.frame = rect
      imageView.image = storyImages[index]
     self.scrollView.addSubview(imageView)           
  }
```

It is working perfectly on all iPhone however same app when executed on iPad horizontal scrolling is lagging. Please advise

Comment: Where are you setting contentSize of scrollview?

Answer (score 1):

It's much better to use UICollectionView for this purpose.

Set scroll direction to Horizontal and Paging enabled for collection view.
And Min spacing
[image]

```
extension FirstViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = indexPath.row % 2 == 0 ? #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.3126001954, blue: 1, alpha: 1) : #colorLiteral(red: 0.1411764771, green: 0.3960784376, blue: 0.5647059083, alpha: 1)
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

}

extension FirstViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return collectionView.frame.size
    }

}
```

Comment: This is the good answer. Collection View reuses cells and doesn't keep everything in memory like Scroll View. Scroll view doesn't render everything at once, but still the whole view hierarchy is in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You have to off lagging of scrollview.

```
self.scrollView.isPagingEnabled = false
```